# SampleRNN - Pytorch implementation beginner

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to start work with this: https://github.com/deepsound-project/samplernn-pytorch
I've installed all the library dependencies through Anaconda console but I'm then not sure how I'm to run the python training scripts.

I guess I just need general help with getting a git RNN in python working? I've found a lot of tutorials that show working from notebooks in Jupyter or even from scratch but can't find ones working from python code files? 
I'm sorry if my terminology is backward, I'm an architect who is attempting coding, note a software engineer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you go to the GitHub page, there are directions for training the  RNN in the readme. Have you tried following them? It looks like you can train the RNN using the following: `python train.py --exp TEST --frame_sizes 16 4 --n_rnn 2 --dataset piano`.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions for getting the SampleRNN implementation working in terminal on the git page. All of the commands listed on the page are for calling the Python scripts from terminal, not from a Jupyter Notebook. If you've installed all the correct dependencies then in theory all you should need to do is call the terminal scripts to try it out.

FYI it took me a while to find a combination of parameters with which this model would train without running into memory errors, but I was working with my own dataset, not the one provided. It's also very intensive - the default train time is 1000 epochs which even on my relatively capable GPU was prohibitively high, so you might want to reduce that value considerably just to reach the end of a training cycle unless you have a sweet setup :)